# Generated a transaction id but not seen on blockchain

Tags: electrum

Transaction id:

> a667e6d1a80c17bd0b55afec7c6ec618ca64a2a6c1b4f9badaf1c883bf5cb5dd

I sent bitcoin from electrum wallet with a 0.002 miner fee but it is showing unconfirmed. I tried to manually broadcast the transaction on blockchain.info but I am getting a transaction rejected because of High S value error.

If I don't see my transaction on the blockchain does that mean that my transaction was not broadcasted on the network? I am hoping that the transaction drops from the network as I do not want to resend.

Answer (score 1):

`High S value error` indicates that a signature in your transaction doesn't adhere to [BIP-62](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0062.mediawiki#low-s-values-in-signatures), i.e. that your signature is non-default. This is the same issue that has been levered in many of the past transaction malleability problems. This could happen for example if you use a very old version of your wallet software.

If your transaction hasn't propagated in the network, you should be able to create a new transaction with the same inputs. It might have been malleated and broadcasted with a different signature though, which would give it a different transaction id. If that's the case you should be able to find it by looking at the addresses of your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Guess your transaction transmit was failing on account of higher fees. Else,
your transaction may have already been transmitted by your wallet and your peers too may have already received the same. This would be in yours and their mempool.

However, because of some error, this transaction has not been picked up any miners and hence remaining unconfirmed.

What you can do is to create a new transaction with the same vins but reduce the fee from 0.002 and give a retry.